# Shadow variable not working in Rust, gives lifetime errors

Tags: rust

Here is my snippet:

```
pub fn abbreviate(mut phrase: &str) -> String {
    let mut tla = String::new();
    phrase = phrase.replace("-", "");
}
```

Gives this error

```
1 | pub fn abbreviate(mut phrase: &str) -> String {
  |                               ---- expected due to this parameter type
...
4 |     phrase = phrase.replace("-", "");
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |              |
  |              expected `&str`, found struct `String`
  |              help: consider borrowing here: `&phrase.replace("-", "")`
```

if I follow the suggestion

```
pub fn abbreviate(mut phrase: &str) -> String {
    let mut tla = String::new();
    phrase = &phrase.replace("-", "");
}
```

I get this lifetime compile error

```
1 | pub fn abbreviate(mut phrase: &str) -> String {
  |                               - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
4 |     phrase = &phrase.replace("-", "");
  |     ----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^- temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |     |         |
  |     |         creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
  |     assignment requires that borrow lasts for `'1`
```

This works but is ugly:

```
pub fn abbreviate(mut phrase: &str) -> String {
    let mut tla = String::new();
    let phrase2 = &phrase.replace("-", "");
}
```

Why can I not shawdow the `phrase` variable? Can somebody please explain the above compiler error about lifetimes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `&str` is a string slice that refers to data held elsewhere. In the case of a string literal, you have a `&'static str` which is a reference to data held in the binary itself. Otherwise, you typically produce a `&str` by taking a slice of an existing `String`.

If you are generating a new string at runtime, the most straightforward way is to make a `String`. You can then dispense slices (`&str`) from it, but the `String` value must itself live at least as long as the slices. `&phrase.replace("-", "")` doesn't work here because you're taking a slice of a *temporary* -- a value that only lives as long as the statement it's part of.  After the end of this statement, the temporary `String` returned by the `replace` method is dropped and `phrase` would refer to a slice that points into a string that no longer exists, and the borrow checker is correctly pointing out that this is not memory-safe.  It would be like returning a reference to a value held in a local variable within the same function.

However, what you're doing here isn't even shadowing, you're just trying to reassign a variable from an incompatible type.  Shadowing the name `phrase` with a new variable of the same name will allow the new name to have a different type (such as `String`), so this would be valid:

```
pub fn abbreviate(phrase: &str) -> String {
    let mut tla = String::new();
    // phrase refers to a &str here
    let phrase = phrase.replace("-", "");
    // phrase refers to a String here

    // Return something
}
```

Basically, your first example only fails because you didn't put `let` before the assignment.

Note also that the `phrase` argument doesn't need to be `mut` here.  `let phrase` introduces a new variable with the same name, effectively hiding the argument from the rest of the function. It doesn't actually change the value held in the original name.